# Laravel Excel import json without escaping quotes

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, import

I'm pretty new to working with json and importing csv/excel files, so perhaps there is a super simple answer to this question.

I have a json field in my database and I can export all data without issues. In my CSV file the data from that particular field looks like below:

```
["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]
```

But when trying to import that same csv/excel file, the data in the database looks like this:

```
""[\"monday\",\"tuesday\",\"wednesday\",\"thursday\",\"friday\",\"saturday\",\"sunday\"]""
```

But I need to get rid of all those slashes since it ofcourse is messing with my code. Preferably I want to import the data so it looks like the original, like so:

```
["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]
```

I did try playing around with `json_encode` and `json_decode` when importing, but it only adds more slashes.

PS. I am using https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly I had import the data like this:

```
json_decode($data, true, 64)
```

I stumbled upon [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/726/how-to-get-rid-of-the-php-warning-json-encode-expects-parameter-2-to-be-long-string-given) site that helped me understand some things better, posting it here in case someone else runs ito similar issues.